# How to skip disabled job on Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, groovy

For running all jobs on Jenkins I use groovy script. I have one disabled job in list and it should be skipped. How to realize it using java/groovy?
Currently running of all jobs stops after skipped job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Jenkins API to determine whether the job is disabled/enabled.  For example,

```
if(Jenkins.instance.getItem("MyDisabledProject").disabled) {
  echo "Job is disabled!"
}
```